# Is ACE working on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ace

I'm looking for an OS abstraction library to use for my next project and I would like to know if ACE (Adaptive Communication Environment) can be used on a windows 7 environment. I've checked the ACE site (www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) but the last version of windows supported is XP. As it seems a big and influent project, this seems strange to me.

Do any one have specific information on ACE support for windows seven or have tried to use it on that system?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 will work with ACE, we do build/test it, but only in XP mode, not using the new Windows 7 API features

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if a future release will work without the XP mode ?

Comment: There are known problems in the threading code when enabling the newer API. We haven't been able to find someone who is willing to fund that work. Maybe your company is, see http://www.theaceorb.nl for our services

Comment: ACE works out of the box without any problems on Windows 7

Comment: Upgrading to 6.3.1 seems to have worked for us, thanks.

Comment: We are still looking for some sponsors so that we can extend ACE to also use the newer Windows API